# how to parse this string in android?

Tags: android, xml, parsing

Here is my code

```
try
        {
            url = new URL("http://localhost/abc//webservice.php?op=login");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("user_email", "abc@abc.com");
            connection.setRequestProperty("user_password", "123456");


            request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            request.write(parameters);
            request.flush();
            request.close();

            if(connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                String line = "";

                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                response = sb.toString();
                isr.close();
                reader.close();
```

This is my response :

```
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8' ?>
   <root>
    <userid>36</userid>
    <message>Successfully Loggin in</message>
   </root>
```

Please tell me how can I get  value of the tags `<userid>` and `<message>`

Comment: what is your problem and whose value you want to get? please describe your question

Comment: I reformatted the code for you (next time use the `{}`button to format the code). However, I think the code is incomplete. You should perhaps review it.

Comment: First, please try to ask questions nicely

Comment: Your code is definitely incomplete. Anyway, Go with whatever @Vladimir has said. its just simple XML

Comment: i want get vaule of userid>36</userid> <message>Successfully Loggin in</message>

Answer (score 5):

Your responce is a simple xml. Parse it with any technology you want:

1. [DOM and SAX](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0408.html&ei=epfCTcuxJsahOo3csZ0I&usg=AFQjCNE6YkFXCJi7hoIUc6KpLtU1i-UlOQ&sig2=YVGsUyIvjVROHq-TPr0tCA)
2. [JAXB](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=http://www.javabeat.net/articles/14-java-60-features-part-2-pluggable-annotation-proce-3.html&ei=n5fCTaGPPIHqOeO2yZ0I&usg=AFQjCNEb_kHQidcuo6L5MY5Ep1B68BuKkg&sig2=1S1ATfvX6p7jNMCKckyp2w)
3. [SimpleXml](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsimple.sourceforge.net%2F&ei=s5fCTcrdOIfrOcy2_Z0I&usg=AFQjCNE40FfELo6ftmZBNkdIi9a-W5QIzQ&sig2=wGLYhLRhuucPQEVu_Q690g)

Comment: Psst: Use the Simple XML library. DOM and SAX are messy, JAXB is missing dependancies on Android and Simple is awesome: http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/